# LINQ to XML: value of sibling if another sibling element exists

Tags: c#, xml, linq

So I have this subset in my XML string:

```
<LOANS>
  <LOAN SequenceNumber="1">
    <LOAN_IDENTIFIERS>
      <LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
        <InvestorLoanIdentifier />
        <LoanIdentifierValue>1234567</LoanIdentifierValue>
      </LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
      <LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
        <SellerLoanIdentifer />
        <LoanIdentifierValue>98765432</LoanIdentifierValue>
      </LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
      <LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
        <MERSMinLoanIdentifer />
        <LoanIdentifierValue>ABCDefgHIJK</LoanIdentifierValue>
      </LOAN_IDENTIFIER>
    </LOAN_IDENTIFIERS>
  </LOAN>
</LOANS>
```

It's not required that all of the types of loan identifier values will be in any set.  I'm trying to figure out how to pull the LoanIdentifierValue values and associate them with the sibling tag for each one.  So far, I've tried this:

```
XmlNamespace ns = "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas_v1_4_2";
var idvals = (from idnumset in rvx.Descendants("LOAN")
             let loannumtype = idnumset.Elements(ns + "LOAN_IDENTIFIERS").Elements(ns + "LOAN_IDENTIFIER")
             let loannumtag = idnumset.Elements(ns + "LOAN_IDENTIFIERS").Elements(ns + "LOAN_IDENTIFIER").Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue")

         select new
         {
             seqnum = (int)int.Parse(idnumset.Attribute("SequenceNumber").Value.ToString())
             ,idset = (from breakoutset in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "InvestorLoanIdentifier") select new { idtype = (string)breakoutset.Name.LocalName, idval = (from breakout2set in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue") select new { val = (string)breakout2set.Value.ToString() ?? null }) })
             ,icid = (from breakoutset in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "InvestorCommitmentIdentifier") select new { idtype = (string)breakoutset.Name.LocalName ?? "NotApplicable", idval = (from breakout2set in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue") select new { val = (string)breakout2set.Value.ToString() ?? null }) })
             ,slid = (from breakoutset in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "SellerLoanIdentifier") select new { idtype = (string)breakoutset.Name.LocalName ?? "NotApplicable", idval = (from breakout2set in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue") select new { val = (string)breakout2set.Value.ToString() ?? null }) })
             ,mmid = (from breakoutset in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "MERS_MINIdentifier") select new { idtype = (string)breakoutset.Name.LocalName ?? "NotApplicable", idval = (from breakout2set in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue") select new { val = (string)breakout2set.Value.ToString() ?? null }) })
             ,svcid = (from breakoutset in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "ServicerLoanIdentifier") select new { idtype = (string)breakoutset.Name.LocalName ?? "NotApplicable", idval = (from breakout2set in loannumtype.Elements(ns + "LoanIdentifierValue") select new { val = (string)breakout2set.Value.ToString() ?? null }) })
          });
```

But it's not working.  The foreach set just skips and goes on its merry way:

```
foreach (var ids in idvals)
{
   seqnum = ids.seqnum;
   foreach (var idv in ids.idset)
   {
      string idtype = idv.idtype;
      if (idtype != "NotApplicable")
         ilia.Add(seqnum, idv.idval.ToString());
   }
   foreach (var sli in ids.slid)
   {
      string slidtype = sli.idtype;
      if (slidtype != "NotApplicable")
         slaa.Add(seqnum, sli.idval.ToString());
   }
   foreach (var mmli in ids.mmid)
   {
     string mmidtype = mmli.idtype;
     if (mmidtype != "NotApplicable")
       mma.Add(seqnum, mmli.idval.ToString());
   }
   foreach (var svcli in ids.svcid)
   {
     string svctype = svcli.idtype;
     if (svctype != "NotApplicable")
        slia.Add(seqnum, svcli.idval.ToString());
   }
   foreach (var icili in ids.icid)
   {
     string ictype = icili.idtype;
     if (ictype != "NotApplicable")
        icia.Add(seqnum, icili.idval.ToString());
   }
}
```

I also tried doing it as a smaller set rather than specifying each name by pulling the Name.LocalName value of the child elements of LOAN_IDENTIFIER, but that fared no better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy.  Here is the nested dictionary

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var dict = doc.Descendants("LOAN").GroupBy(l => (string)l.Attribute("SequenceNumber"),
                    m => m.Descendants("LOAN_IDENTIFIER")
                      .GroupBy(x => x.Elements().FirstOrDefault().Name.LocalName, y => (string)y.Elements().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault())
                      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: How do I include the SequenceNumber attribute from the parent LOAN tag?  That'll be required to differentiate sets (there will be several sets of LOAN in the XML data).  I tried making a nested Dictionary set but I keep getting stuck on how to separate them.

Comment: Now made nested dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, and a zillion more times thank you!   Works a treat!

Comment: You can make Sequence Number a number using : (int)l.Attribute("SequenceNumber")